# 'exit'-Event in worker process when killed from master within a node.js cluster

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'd like to gracefully exit a child-process from the master process, where master and child code are in different .js files.

**master.js**

```
cluster.setupMaster({
  exec : 'child.js',
  args : [],
  silent : false
});
cluster.fork({'some': 'info'});

process.on('SIGINT', function() {
  console.log('\nshutting down services ...');
  function eachWorker(callback) {
    for (var id in cluster.workers) {
      callback(cluster.workers[id]);
    }
  }
  eachWorker(function(worker) {
    worker.kill();
  });
  process.exit(0);
})
```

**child.js**

```
cluster.worker.on('disconnect', function() {
  console.log(cluster.worker.id + ' shutting down.');
})
```

I tried various signals, cluster.worker.on('exit'), process.on('exit'), process.on('disconnect') etc. but none seems to be triggered. Any ideas?

worker.send() works during execution time, but not within the SIGINT function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Node.js (or my Mac) appears to be handling ctrl-c and SIGINT slightly differently.  When I ctrl-c both child processes are forcefully quit before the master process exits.  If I start `master.js` in the background and `kill -SIGINT [pid]`, the code executes correctly, the children get the notification and all is good with the world.

There are several things you can do to remedy this situation.  The first is to actually kill using SIGINT and not ctrl-c.  The second is to add a `process.on('SIGINT')` to the child process.  Something simple like:

```
process.on('SIGINT', function() {
    console.log('\nshutting down ...');
    setTimeout(function() { console.log('quitting'); process.exit(0); }, 10000);
});
```

will give the children time to shut down properly.  (obviously the goal is to quit within the 10 seconds given)

To handle the messages on the client you want to:

```
var cluster = require('cluster');
var worker = cluster.worker;
worker.on('message', function(msg) {
        console.log("message for worker: " );
        console.log(msg);
        if (msg == "exit) ...
});
```

In your `eachWorker(function...`

```
worker.send("exit");
```

This may actually be the result of a bug in node.js.  cluster is still "experimental"

Comment: I've added some more info on the spawning. worker.send() works when I put it somewhere in the master.js code, but not within the SIGINT procedure.

Comment: I came to the same conclusion after trying out a few things. Instead of the message, you can use cluster.disconnect([callback]) to proceed once all workers are disconnected. Seems to work.

Comment: This helps with gulp-nodemon w/ express clusters immensely.